# Msg 8905: DBCC CHECKALLOC Error Messages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption

We recently experienced a database corruption and run integrity checks. DBCC CHECKDB returned a lot of consistency errors and 2 allocation errors. 
We have fixed consistency errors by moving data, droping and recreating related objects.

Now we have left 2 allocation errors and we don't know how to resolve them. Can anyone advice us on how to find the cause of these errors?

Below is the code we run;

```
DBCC CHECKALLOC([DBNAME]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

The results;

> Msg 8905, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Extent (1:9612464) in database ID
>   22 is marked allocated in the GAM, but no SGAM or IAM has allocated
>   it.
>
> Msg 8905, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Extent (1:9617504) in database ID
>   22 is marked allocated in the GAM, but no SGAM or IAM has allocated
>   it.
>
> CHECKALLOC found 2 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors not
>   associated with any single object.
>
> CHECKALLOC found 2 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in
>   database 'DBNAME'.
>
> repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors
>   found by DBCC CHECKALLOC (DBNAME, noindex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to take a backup and restore the database to a different server and then run `DBCC CHECKDB ...repair_allow_data_loss`. This way you will know if there is any data loss or not.

Refer to [my answer for more details](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54744/8783).

If you have a good backup that you can restore, I would prefer to go with that and export the data out of the corrup database. You can use redgate's data compare (not free, but I have used it and its a lifesaver).

Make sure you do diagnosis of your hardware and update driver firmware to latest version and are on the [latest supported service pack for sql server 2008R2](http://sqlserverupdates.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Kin. I have restored a copy of db and run REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS. It fixed both allocation errors. But I am not sure if any data is lost. Is there a way to find what kind of data is lost? Result message is;

`
 'Repair: The extent (1:9617504) has been deallocated from object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 72057594965786624 (type Unknown).'
Extent (1:9612464) in database ID 32 is marked allocated in the GAM, but no SGAM or IAM has allocated it.
        The error has been repaired.
`

Comment: just do a row count from the original and restored copy.

Comment: I did it and there is no data loss. All corruptions are fixed. Thank you again.